# unable to trigger a event on jquery daterange picker?

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-events

I am using jquery daterange picker but could not find event that will give me a selected date range.

here is my date picker looks like
https://snag.gy/SqiOPK.jpg

**html**

```
<div id="example-advanced-daterangepicker" data-step="1" data-intro="This is a date range selector!">
       <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
         <span>April 6, 17 - April 6, 17</span>
       <b class="caret"></b>
</div>
```

Comment: paste some of your code or make a fiddle to analyze what's going wrong?

Comment: ok I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have looked in [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-daterangepicker) URL to find out your solution.

I have found some couple of events there to use for giving selected date range.

```
getValue (Function)
```

You can call this function inside the event that triggered on date range picker. Like,

```
.bind('datepicker-change',function(event,obj)
{
  // It will fire while selecting date range from the picker. SO you can set your code here something to get selected date range

  console.log(obj); // By using this object you will sure find some solution to get a range between two dates.
  date1: (Date object of the earlier date)
  date2: (Date object of the later date),   
}
```

For more help, you can check [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-daterangepicker) URL. It will be helpful for you. Thanks.